# How to plot data set on different plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I run this code, I do have one plot printing my two data sets a and b. I would like them to be displayed on two separate plots. Thanks in advance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(0,10)
b= range(2,12)

plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
```

Comment: You're asking a design question. SO is really about helping you fix code that doesn't work. Please, attempt a solution and post it here so we can discuss how your solution can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) shows how to do this. You need to utilize the `show()` method after each plot.

```
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()
plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you can show both at the same time utilizing [subplots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html):

```
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(a)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(b)

plt.show()
```

This creates the following plot:

[image: Subplots]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `show()` method :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(0,10)
b= range(2,12)

plt.plot(a)
plt.show()

plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Merci Paul :) ca aide beaucoup